# Same transistor type, swapped emitter and collectors? Normal?

Tags: transistors

Maybe it's just my basic understanding of transistors but I noticed the following with my transistors..

I have about 20 transistors of the same type, (in this case all BC547). But when I measure them with my 'trusty' transistor-meter it indicates that with some of them the emitter and collector switch places. Is this normal? I would think that there is a 'standard' pinout for these types of generic transistortypes.

Perhaps this is just a silly question, but I never really noticed this before ... that is, until I tried to get my project going and it would fail because of the swapped pins of the transistor.

Hope some of you are willing to shed some light on this for me. Trying to learn here.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: They will work, although poorly, when reversed. Take some of your "reversed" ones and check Hfe both ways round. Also, do any of them have a suffix (K or L) that indicate a different packaging? That is a common source of confusion in TO92 devices

Comment: How certain are you they are identical part numbers?  There are lots of transistors that look the same but have different pinouts.  Just making sure you haven't ruled this out.

Comment: I don't know about the BC547, as I'm not comprehensively informed about it. But there are two different pinouts for the P2N2222A (a CBE pinout) and the PN2222 (EBC pinout.) So at least given my BC547 ignorance it seems at least possible in concept that other devices may have varying pinouts as I already know one example where it happens. But I doubt it. Most likely its something else going on with your trusty meter.

Comment: Which 'trusty' transistor-meter do you have, and how does it tell you the Collector and Emitter are swapped?

Answer (score 3):

bipolar transistors work somewhat if you swap collector and emitter, with BC547 I would expect the \$ h_{FE} \$ figure to be around 100 to 800 with it connected forwards and about 3 to 50 with it connected backwards.

BC547 has in the past been available in several different lead configurations. 0.05" pitch, 0.1" pitch, TO-18 compatible, etc, I don't recall if there was one that was truly backwards.

Answer (score 1):

For a given device number, transistor pinouts are pretty much always the same, even from different manufacturers. The only way I can think of that the transistors themselves would have different pinouts is if they were fakes.

If you're tester is showing collector and emitter reversed it's almost guaranteed to be because the tester is getting it wrong. Go by what the documentation for the transistor you're using says.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet shows the pins of a transistor and has maximum allowed voltage ratings.
If you connect collector and emitter pins backwards then the maximum allowed voltages are very different:

[image: BC547]